# Will a php include have to download if inside a false "if" statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, include

I wanted to know if I include a .php file (or any file for that matter) inside of an if statement like so:

```
<?php
    $a = 1;
    if($a == 0) include 'somefile.php';
?>
```

Since that then would be false, would the somefile.php be loaded by the browser at all or would it not be loaded, resulting in a smaller amount of data having to be downloaded by the client?

Comment: It won't be. You can easily test it by inspecting Apache's access log.

Comment: I was thinking more in the way of instead of putting the contents of "somefile.php" to be executed in the if statement, that would increase the size of the file right? So if the code is included in a separate file will it then be smaller?

Comment: If you include extra code into a script then the script contains extra code.

Comment: @Tinman, no, this is not the way things work. The PHP is processed at the server and only the result of that is sent to the browser. As such, it doesn't matter how large the source file is when wanting to know how much data is sent to the client, and the output is never actually changed.

Comment: @Jasper thanks, exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 2):

First of all its not loaded by the browser but by php on the server. And no it will not be loaded when the condition is false.

As Jasper pointed out: Whatever you include in a php script has very little to do with how much is sent to the browser. Php interprets the code and creates html that is sent to the user's browser. You could have a 1000000 lines of codes file that just echoes "1" and the browser would get only a couple of kb of data. Even if 100 megs of php where processed.

It is pretty easy to test. Create a dummy.php file containing:

```
<?php echo 'hello world';
```

To test this:

```
if(true){ include("dummy.php");} //will echo hello world
if(false){ include("dummy.php");} //will not echo hello world
```

To test it try it with passing true and the false to the if and you will see two different results.

Then include this file in an if statemant and see if it echoes hello world.

Comment: That test does not show anything at all. I mean, if it works the way it does, nothing is echo'd. If it is interpreted as `if (false) echo 'hello world'` still nothing is shown.

Comment: @Jasper I meant try it with true then false and see the difference.

Comment: That changes nothing. Compare to the `#include` preprocessor directive in C/C++. There, the file would be included, but not executed. However, you would get the same results here whether or not the file is included but not executed or isn't included.

Comment: Files are not "executed" in php the way you seem to think. Or I am missing something in your explanation. The answer to the guy's question is NO it will not be included if the if statement is false. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Jasper: In php, the php statements in the included file will be executed.  So I don't know what you are trying to say?  If the file is included here, the text "Hello World" will be displayed.  If it isn't, that text will not be shown.

Comment: I do know how it works in PHP. However, what I am saying is that to answer the question (`Are include statements that are never reached in php processed at all?`) you need to show a distinction between the way it works in php and the way it works in C. Now your samples give the exact same output in both cases, so those tests can't answer the question.

Comment: @Jasper: I must be missing something.  Firstly, why should we consider C if this question is about php.  Secondly, how do you mean Iznogood's samples give the exact output in both cases?   They don't. 'Both cases' meaning `if (false)` and if (`true`), right? Or do you mean if(C) and if(php)?  If so, do you mean `if (php && false)` or `if(php && true)`?

Comment: My bad read don't for some reason. Deleted my comment.

Comment: @Stefan Basically, the question was how does `X` work. There are multiple ways it could work. One of those is the way it actually works in php and another is how it actually works in C. Now, if you want to give proof of how it works in php, you need to show that it doesn't work the way it actually does work in C. That's the context in which I used C.

Comment: @Stefan As for the what I mean with both cases is that all samples given by Iznogood would give the same response if the file was accessed and interpreted, but not executed (the "C" way) as the same samples when it is never even accessed (the actual php way)

Comment: I feel like I am getting trolled. Ha ha. Oh well done with this question. To thin k of the debate we had for a question that got 7 downvotes.

Comment: @Jasper: Seems to be a question of definitions.  Basically you are making a distinction between 'loaded' (= accessed and interpreted) versus 'excecuted'.  You noticed that the OP was concerned about the 'loading' aspect without him realizing that it doesn't work like that in php.  So perhaps the simple answer is that the include file is not accessed in any way if the if statement is false, and if it is true, then 'loading' should be 'executing'.  Anyway!  Maybe it wasn't such a bad question after all.

Comment: @Iznogood: Well at least you got 3 votes for your answer (so far)!

Comment: The OP was worried about the amount of data sent to the client. His mistake in that was that the source isn't sent to the client. However, you could be interested in the same info on the server side, for example if you are worried about compiling/execution speeds or want to make sure your php is cached optimally. In that case, the question would be `Is there a difference in the amount of code processed when using an include is reached or not`, which makes the same difference.

Comment: @Stefan actually I got 4 but Jasper downvoted me (as is his right). I don't care about the points that much.

Comment: For what its worht I edited my answer to adresss what seems to be the main question about how much data is sent to the browser.

Comment: To take things a little further even, say I put my dummy page on another server, eg. http://mysite.com/dummy.txt, and my including page becomes `<? if($something) include 'http://mysite.com/dummy.php' ?>` the question as originally posted suddenly makes sense again (does php need to download my dummy page from the other site if `$something` is `false`) and basically, you have the same distinction again.